# Images doesn't loading with Glide

Tags: android

When I'm using *Glide* to load images to *ImageButtons*, some images are doesn't loading. I hope someone know any solution to my problem.

Here's my code:

.xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/csik_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib2_the_dancer"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib3_shadowman"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_ib2_the_dancer"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib4_keplers_dream"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_ib1_24_hours_to_live"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib5_drawning_home"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_ib4_keplers_dream"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib6_another_wolfcop"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib3_shadowman"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_ib5_drawning_home"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib7_monster_truck"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib4_keplers_dream"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_ib4_keplers_dream"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib8_underworld_blood_wars"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib5_drawning_home"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_ib9_the_disaster_artist"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="155dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/home_ib6_another_wolfcop"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(The whole .xml is in *RelativeLayout* outside the *ScrollView*)

.java:

```
ImageButton home_ib1_24_hours_to_live;
ImageButton home_ib2_the_dancer;
ImageButton home_ib3_shadowman;
ImageButton home_ib4_keplers_dream;
ImageButton home_ib5_drawning_home;
ImageButton home_ib6_another_wolfcop;
ImageButton home_ib7_monster_truck;
ImageButton home_ib8_underworld_blood_wars;
ImageButton home_ib9_the_disaster_artist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    home_ib1_24_hours_to_live = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_24_hours_to_live)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib1_24_hours_to_live);

    home_ib2_the_dancer = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib2_the_dancer);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_the_dancer)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib2_the_dancer);

    home_ib3_shadowman = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib3_shadowman);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_shadowman)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib3_shadowman);

    home_ib4_keplers_dream = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib4_keplers_dream);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_kerlers_dream)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib4_keplers_dream);

    home_ib5_drawning_home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib5_drawning_home);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_drawing_home)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib5_drawning_home);

    home_ib6_another_wolfcop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib6_another_wolfcop);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_another_wolfcop)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib6_another_wolfcop);

    home_ib7_monster_truck = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib7_monster_truck);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_monster_truck)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib7_monster_truck);

    home_ib8_underworld_blood_wars = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib8_underworld_blood_wars);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_underworld_blood_wars)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib8_underworld_blood_wars);

    home_ib9_the_disaster_artist = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_ib9_the_disaster_artist);
    Glide.with(Home.this)
            .load(R.drawable.moviep_the_disaster_artist)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(home_ib9_the_disaster_artist);
```

You can see all my code, and downbelow a picture of the problem.. And when I restarted the app it worked, and when I restarted again, it doesn't worked, but another pictures are doesn't loaded (so we can say it "working" randomly).
And I added this line to my *Build.Gradle*/app : compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
(And the LogCat doesn't "say" anything goes wrong)

Here's the picture:
[In the red line would be an antoher image like the others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mgEE.jpg)

In the red line would be an antoher image like the others.

Thanks for the help in advance.
(My average response time is 30 minutes)

Edit: 
If any memory cache is skipped, how can I to not skip the cache?

Comment: check your log if any memory cache is skipped.

Comment: And how can I to not skip the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is nothing wrong with the code, what's your min API level?

Trace your log to see if there is cache skipping. If it won't help try this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow () {
        Glide.clear(this);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        } else {
            setBackground(null);
        }
        setImageBitmap(null);
        System.gc();
    }
```

Comment: My min API level is 21. And maybe this is the problem: " E/libEGL: cache file failed CRC check "                                                        
How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you using drawables if you are gonna use Glide? either set them as src in your xml or get them from the url. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html